# Where does application version show in google analytics reports?

Tags: google-analytics

I am setting the appVersion in my analytics code:

```
ga('set', 'appVersion', 'v3');
```

Where does this appear in the reports?

UPDATE 1:

In reporting I have set a customisation report like http://cl.ly/image/1Z1x0C0L0n00

But the app version is not showing http://cl.ly/image/0v3A0m0o392O

Comment: I don't think it appears in the standard reports, but you can create a custom dimension with the appVersion which would then be reported.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but its not reporting for some reason. Please see update on question.

Comment: Is your GA web property set up for mobile apps? If so, you would be able to see it under Audience > App Versions.

Comment: Is application version only for mobile apps then? Ours is a web app but we have two versions at the moment.